# Pro Vagrant Exercise Error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am going thru the pro vagrant book and having the following problem with the first exercise.

I am using:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

I have installed Oracle VirtualBox (64 bit version) and Vagrant (64 bit version)

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "apache-v1.0.0"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://boxes.gajdaw.pl/apache/apache-v1.0.0.box"
  config.vm.box_download_checksum_type = "sha256"
  config.vm.box_download_checksum = "091eb90af1bce5dd1dc936ed9db9ef65631e7428c29e60b395025a2d21cdc463"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8800, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.post_up_message = "The application is available at http://127.0.0.1:8800"
end
```

Upon carrying out the steps for the first exercise

I get the following error:

```
pro-vagrant/songs-app-angularjs$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8800 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Gurdipe

Comment: I would check 2 things. 1st remove the `host-ip` from the `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8800, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` ; 2nd check in Virtual Box if you can boot the machine and connect with vagrant user

Comment: I removed the `, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` from  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8800, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" and checked that I can log onto the virtual box with user: vagrant and password: vagrant but still having the same problem.